# Multiple alias in one account

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app, fortrabbit

I never used fortrabbit before and i have a question about it.
I know i can create apps and define the document root, but lets imagine the following:

I want to go with Yii2 Framework (Advanced template)

Advanced template have "two apps" in it (2 folders) the backend and the frontend.

On a real server we have to create two alias, eg:

1. admin.myapp.com -> root/backend/www
2. www.myapp.com ->   root/frontend/www

Is possible to configure the fortrabbit to work with it within the same application and share the same resources (MySQL, cache, etc)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your setup is possible at fortrabbit.
Just put both folders in your git repo and push to forrabbit. After that you can route the subdomains (www., admin.) to the subfolders (frontend/www, backend/www).

If your project requires a `composer install` during the deploy process it will not work our of the box, since we check only for the composer.json/lock in the root of your project.

However you can define your custom post-deploy scripts. In these script you could call a `composer install` in the subfolders.

Cheers
Oliver (fortrabbit staff)

Comment: Thanks, thats all i need :) 
composer will be always at root, so no problem with it